# Nginx is not Reloading, but it is restarting fine

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx

I have installed Nginx on AWS instance, everything is working fine like I can start the Nginx, restart it, stop it, etc, but I am not able to reload it. Even the "nginx -t" is giving the test as successful.

The error I am getting when trying to reload it is:

```
# systemctl reload nginx
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: The error recommends two places to check. Did you check those two places?

Comment: @karan525 I recommend you for quickly response move your question to `https://serverfault.com/` or `https://superuser.com/`.

Comment: Update your question the next results please `systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe`

Comment: The errors that I am seeing are: 
    Nov 22 19:24:19 ip-172-31-8-183 systemd[1]: Reload failed for The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer by myself. I had customized my Nginx install. I have changed the sbin path as:

```
--sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx
```

Now I have changed that to default:

```
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx
```

Now it worked fine. But I still don't get it, why it was restarting fine but not reloading. If anyone can answer, that would be helpful.